# How to authenticate with Nginx and Microsoft Azure AD?

Tags: azure, nginx

I need to have comfortable way to allow auth for specific users from AAD to upstream application with Nginx.
I found some information:

- AAD does not support LDAP -> its overkill anyway. So ldap is last solution for me
- Oauth2_proxy by bitly works OK, only for specific list of user which
  has to be edited in file (in place). There is open PR for Group access support
  https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy/pull/347, but seems that
  oauth2_proxy is unsupported now. -> That would be a fine, because I can manage user access in AAD.
- There is tutorial how to setup JWT tokens in nginx
  https://www.nginx.com/blog/conditional-access-control-with-microsoft-azure-active-directory/
  -> but only in paid version of nginx
- There are a lot of lua scripts for openresty
  https://github.com/SkyLothar/lua-resty-jwt, but they are ehm,
  unmaintained in most cases.

EDIT:
Maybe this is 3rd party jwt foss module for nginx https://github.com/TeslaGov/ngx-http-auth-jwt-module

EDIT2:
lua-resty-openidc for openresty looks great, even maintained.
Only Azure example is missing.

EDIT3:
I am wondering if is possible to use

AAD -> Keycloak -> Keycloak Proxy -> Nginx (auth_request to keycloak proxy)

?

Is there any rock solid alternative?
Thanks

Comment: There is also this, works with AD, does not need admin bind password (not tested with azure though): https://bitbucket.org/sivann/nginx-ldap-authrequest-handler/src/master/

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with AAD, but if you already have a client authorised within your environment then the Nginx [auth request module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) is a very simple way of delegating authentication for upstream services to your existing authorisation server.

Example directives in Nginx:

```
location /upstream/ {
    auth_request /auth;
    ...
}

location = /auth {
    proxy_pass http://your-auth-server:1234;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Authorization $http_authorization;
}
```

Nginx will make an internal subrequest to /auth for every client request to /upstream/, which you proxy to your auth server, passing whatever info you need to authorise the client request. In this example the client ip and their authorization header.

Your auth server does it's thing and then responds with http code 200 if you want to allow access, or 401/403 if not. Nginx then allows or denies the client request based upon the response code.